# Laravel-API using session issue: Auth::id() is null

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-8, laravel-api

We are trying to access current logged user's id, We modified the auth.php file in this way:

```
'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

and after this we edidted also the Kernel.php file:

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

in Our Route api.php We have this:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('api')->group(function(){

Route::post('/tipo', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createtipo']);
Route::post('/corso', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createcorso']);
Route::get('/mostracorsi', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorsi']);
Route::get('/mostracorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorso']);
Route::put('/updatecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'updatecorso']);
Route::delete('/deletecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deletecorso']);


Route::post('/iscrizione', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'iscrizione']);
Route::get('/vedicorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'vedicorso']);
Route::delete('/deleteiscrizione/{idUtente}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deleteiscrizione']);


Auth::routes();

}));
```

In our Controller We have this:

```
public function createcorso(Request $request)
{

    $corsoscii = new CorsoScii();
    $admin_id = new AdminController();

    $corsoscii->tipo = $request->input('tipo');
    $corsoscii->nome = $request->input('nome');
    $corsoscii->membriMax = $request->input('membriMax');
    $corsoscii->orario_inizio = $request->input('orario_inizio');
    $corsoscii->orario_fine = $request->input('orario_fine');
    $corsoscii->inizio = $request->input('inizio');
    $corsoscii->fine = $request->input('fine');

    $corsoscii->save();

    $idUtente = Auth::id();
    $idCorso = CorsoScii::latest()->first();
    DB::table('iscrizione')->insert(
        array('idUtente' => $idUtente, 'idCorso' => $idCorso)
    );
    return response()->json($corsoscii);
}
```

We chose this way because everytime we pass the current user id on our controller it was always null:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'idUtente' cannot be null

When we tried to do again the ajax call it gives us the following error in our browser console:

> binding exception target class not found

In case Could be an useful info we have also the route list, We tried to understand what is wrong looking here:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                             | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                       |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                               |                  | Closure                                                                | web                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                           | admin            | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | Laratrust\Middleware\LaratrustRole:administrator |
|        | POST     | api/corso                       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@createcorso                         | api                                              |
|        | DELETE   | api/deletecorso/{idCorso}       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@deletecorso                         | api                                              |
|        | DELETE   | api/deleteiscrizione/{idUtente} |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@deleteiscrizione                    | api                                              |
|        | POST     | api/iscrizione                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@iscrizione                          | api                                              |
|        | POST     | api/login                       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/login                       | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | POST     | api/logout                      | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | api                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/mostracorsi                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@mostracorsi                         | api                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/mostracorso/{idCorso}       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@mostracorso                         | api                                              |
|        | POST     | api/password/confirm            |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/password/confirm            | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | auth                                             |
|        | POST     | api/password/email              | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | api                                              |
|        | POST     | api/password/reset              | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | api                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/password/reset              | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | api                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/password/reset/{token}      | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | api                                              |
|        | POST     | api/register                    |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/register                    | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | POST     | api/tipo                        |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@createtipo                          | api                                              |
|        | PUT      | api/updatecorso/{idCorso}       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@updatecorso                         | api                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                        |                  | Closure                                                                | api                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | auth:api                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/vedicorso/{idCorso}         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@vedicorso                           | api                                              |
|        | POST     | cancella/{id}                   | cancellautente   | App\Http\Controllers\ClienteController@delete                          | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | Laratrust\Middleware\LaratrustRole:user          |
|        | GET|HEAD | cliente                         | cliente          | App\Http\Controllers\ClienteController@index                           | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | Laratrust\Middleware\LaratrustRole:user          |
|        | POST     | login                           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                           | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | POST     | logout                          | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm                | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | auth                                             |
|        | POST     | password/confirm                |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | auth                                             |
|        | POST     | password/email                  | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset                  | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web                                              |
|        | POST     | password/reset                  | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}          | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                        | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
|        | POST     | register                        |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web                                              |
|        |          |                                 |                  |                                                                        | guest                                            |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try do a `dd(Auth::check())` and see if the returned boolean is true or false

Comment: We tried to print the current user id on our dashboard template usign always Auth::id() retrieved from a User admin controller and the printing was successfully.

Comment: When we tried to use Auth::id() inside a Controller it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `auth:api` in your `api` middleware group.

```
    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

Comment: We tried to add 'auth:api' into middleware group but now it gives us this error: `"message":"Unauthenticated."}{↵    "message": "Target class [bindings] does not exist.",↵    "exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException`

Comment: Replace `bindings` with `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class`, since both are just the same. I edited my answer.

Comment: The bindings class exception not found is solved but the problem is the error 401: `responseJSON: {message: "Unauthenticated."}
responseText: "{"message":"Unauthenticated."}"`

Comment: For the Unauthenticated error, you must have an active session. Logging in a user should suffice.

Comment: We already have an active session, How can we pass the active session in our controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `middleware('auth')` since every route inside api.php is already assigned to `middleware('api')`.

Comment: We changed from `middleware('api')` into `middleware('auth')` but it gives us this error: `responseJSON: {message: "Unauthenticated."} responseText: "{"message":"Unauthenticated."}"`

Comment: I don't know about you, but this suffices in my middlewareGroup: `'api' => [
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
'throttle:60,1',
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class]`

Comment: But in the example you provided about, there are way more array items. I'm not sure if you need them all.

Comment: We were not sure if we needed all the array items provided in our question, we deleted the ones not necessary.